# SQL Server 2014 Database NDF file Lost - Filegroup offline

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2014, data-recovery, dynamics-nav

I have a database that has lost one of its `.ndf` files and have been unable to get at the data. The `.ndf` file in question was added last Thursday and placed in a temporary storage location by a colleague (d'oh!). There is no backup available from this database since prior to this `.ndf` being created. I have seen numerous solutions to similar problems when the `.ndf` in question is its own filegroup, but in this case it actually is in a filegroup with an additional file which I want to try and get data from. I am pretty sure what I am trying to do is not possible but there is always a chance right?

The database setup

- PRIMARY: `Data.mdf` -200mb
- Data Filegroup 1: `Data_1.ndf` - 2.9gb
- `Data_2.ndf`  - 64gb (newly added file that is now lost - I believe it is just preallocated space)
- LOG: `Log.ldf` - 128mb

When we logged into the VM this morning (hosted in Azure), we were presented with an unexpected shutdown notification from Windows (it seems there was a powerloss/shutdown at 1am) and our application was not reaching the database. Looking in SQL Server Management Studio I could see that it was Recovery Pending status. Trying to bring the db online lead me to an error about `Data_2.ndf` not being found (located at `D:\SQL\Data\Data_2.ndf`).

When I accessed the D drive (temporary storage drive) I was presented with a wonderful blank Windows Explorer window - completely blank drive.

I was able to set the `Data_2.ndf` file offline and bring the database itself online, however I am not able to query any of the data (as all tables were in Data Filegroup 1) due to the filegroup being offline. The other 3 files (`mdf, ndf, ldf`) are all online.

Is there any way out of this? Any way to perhaps recover any remaining data from `Data_1.ndf` or is it completely toast?

(This was a hastily stood up development server and there was no backup/recovery strategy for it, as "Azure never crashes" :)).

(Edit:formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hosed. Its a miracle you can bring up your database. Are you sure you can retrieve data - have you tried doing selects? You probably will receive more extensive answers on the Database Administrators group.

Comment: As I figured/was expecting - thanks.    I cannot select any data as I get

Msg 8653, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
The query processor is unable to produce a plan for the table or view 'Object' because the table resides in a filegroup that is not online.

Comment: Your only hope is to be really obnoxious to the Azure people to get them to find a backup to your files. I don't know how Azure works but that is where I put my energy.